# How to make tomcat serve static files from webpack dev server?

Tags: tomcat, webpack, webpack-dev-server

We have a tomcat server for APIs and a webpack server for frontend development.

The tomcat server handles authentication and receives an auth token from an auth provider. This token has to be used in all requests from my webpack server too. We are not allowed to use localhost for security reasons. So i need tomcat to serve static files from webpack. I have figured out the wiring for the final build which puts the js bundle in the war file. But i cant figure it out for development server.

We dont have httpd or nginx for reverse proxying.

How can I proxy static resources in Tomcat to webpack dev server? Should I add a connector in server.xml or something like that?

org.website.com/index.html -> locahost:3000/index.html

Comment: webapck-dev-server is for development, so it usually should work with DEV Server Api.
And Dev Server should use Dev Auth which you can configure in the way you want not considering security or whatever. Then you just use webpack proxy -- so you run webpack and it proxy all api/* requests.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov im not looking to proxy api requests from webpack to tomcat. I want tomcat to serve static files from webpack. Look at my answer to understand.

Answer (score 0):

So we added nginx and I figured this out by adding a single server block which handles the proxying logic for both tomcat and dev server. I'm able to serve the webpack dev server from publicPath '/dev/'. So mydomain.com/ will serve tomcat's index.html and mydomain.com/dev will serve webpack's content. This way I can query the backend tomcat api while getting hot reloading in mydomain.com/dev.

```sh
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    proxy_read_timeout 3500s;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate ../cert/mydomain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key ../cert/mydomain.key;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location /dev/ {
      proxy_pass https://localhost:3000;
      expires off;
    }

    location /sockjs-node/ {
        proxy_pass          https://localhost:3000;
      proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
      expires off;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_redirect http:// https://;
      proxy_pass https://localhost:8443;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_request_buffering off;
      expires off;
    }

  }
```

I hope this helps someone.